# Temperature measurement in strong AC magnetic field

Tags: temperature, heat, coil, electromagnetic, induction

I have a coil that is continously driven with a maximum of 100A RMS of current at a frequency of 20kHz. The coil is water-cooled and I would like to directly monitor its temperature. The temperature sensor will be placed on the coil and will need to relay the signal to a microcontroller over 1.5m of wire that will be running in close proximity to the wires powering the coil. The sensor will therefore need to be resistant to being induction-heated by the coil, and the circuit reading out the temperature needs to be immune to the noise picked up by the long wires. My question is: what type of temperature sensor and corresponding circuit would be suitable for this situation?

Comment: Look up fiber optic thermometry. It's what power companies use. It's an area where I have expertise.

Comment: Or measure the temperature of the coolant.

Comment: Budget per measurement point is an important factor to include in your question. This may eliminate the use of an FOT. For thinking purposes, in some cases you may also consider simply painting the surface to be monitored with a phosphorescent paint (cheap) and aim a pulsed laser or LED at it and then read it with optics.

Comment: Costs can be made reasonable. I built a fully functional system (FOT, not "painted") for a few hundred US dollars. The temperature range of a single, physical unit is broadly speaking spans between -200 C and about 500 C, after which the timing gets pretty fast and the electronics gets more expensive. It's pretty impressive and can be readily calibrated to be accurate to half a Kelvin over that range. But this also depends upon the chosen phosphor, as well. And there are thousands of choices there, so I'm only speaking about those phosphors I've directly used, myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions! Cost of a few hundred dollars is certainly managable. I will look into fiber optic telemtry. Measuring the temperature of the coolant is also a good idea which I will fall back on in case a direct a measurement is infeasible.

Comment: @KhaledNasr I worked with Dr. Wickersheim and Dr. Sun. Dr. Wickersheim is dead, now. And I will never willingly work with/for Dr. Sun (long story.) But you can see a paper of theirs [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08327823.1987.11688010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like jonk said, fiber optics are a great solution for your problem, but what you get will depend on your budget.  Older infrared monitors are decently cheap, though, but might require some work to interface with newer equipment.

[Here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/311264320139)'s a set I found on e-bay for US$35.00

[Some newer equipment can be a lot more expensive, however...](https://www.omega.com/en-us/temperature-measurement/fiber-optic-temperature-measurement/fom-series/p/FOM-L201-2?utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=organicshopping)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! I will look into it and see if it can fit into the system.